# Sqoop and Vertica

Tags: sqoop, vertica

Is there anyone here who has worked with sqoop and hp vertica?

I am trying to export data from sqoop to vertica and I find that the performance is extremely poor.

I can switch to the HP vertica connector... but I still want to know why sqoop works so slow when exporting data to vertica.

I also found that when inserting data, sqoop does not support upserts against vertica. I want to know if this issue will be fixed anytime soon?

```
sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --driver 
com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --mysql-delimiters  --username **** --password **** --
connect jdbc:vertica://hostname/schema?ConnectionLoadBalance=1 --export-dir <hdfs-
data-dir> --table <table_name>
```

One of the issues is that sqoop if forcing us to set `sqoop.export.records.per.statement` to 1 for Vertica. Otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: What's the sqoop command you are using?

Comment: @woot I scream scoop.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used sqoop, but the command line data import function in vertica uses the COPY function; basically it makes a temp file and then runs a file import in the background. It wouldn't be a graceful solution, but you could try dumping your data to a gzip and then running the COPY function directly. I find that the gzip is always the bottleneck for files over a certain threshold (~50Mb+), never the COPY. Could be a backdoor to a faster import.

Answer (score 0):

i work sqoop with vertica database, i use sqoop to export data from the vertica to the hive/HDFS and it work grate, you just need to add the vertica jar to the sqoop folder.
when i want to asq vertica on data that in the HDFS/Hive i use the hcatalog of the vertica. in version 8.1.* it comes with the vertica database and you don't need more connectors.

[hcatalog](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HCatalogConnector/UsingTheHCatalogConnector.htm)